# flash 8 loadvars from another domain

Tags: flash

I have a flash 8 swf file at www.mydomain.com and I need to access data from a webservice at http://www.regonline.com/webservices/memberauthorization.asmx/authorizeMemberWithEmailAddress

I am trying to do this with the loadvars class and this all works fine in the flash ide but when I put the swf on mydomain.com it gives an error.

I assume this is a cross domain issue but I really do not understand this area and assume that I cannot place a cross domain policy file on the regonline server.

Could any one shed some light on this. Been googling for a couple of hours and am no closer to a solution.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is for the "other" server to explicitly allow you to load from it by placing a crossdomain.xml specifying your access in it's root, in this case that would be at http://www.regonline.com/crossdomain.xml

However, since you're not in control of this server that won't be possible.

The best solution is to have a proxy script on your server that your flash app can call, wgeb the flash load this your server contacts the third party server with the supplied data and sends the response back to the flash.

You can find examples of [php proxy scripts](http://xmlrpcflash.mattism.com/proxy_info.php) all over the web.

Comment: Thank you so much for this input. I needed to use asp but found a suitable script and it works perfectly.